# Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to WebElement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting error"Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to WebElement"
when tried to run a java file to check broken images on webpage.

**My Code :**

```
 List elementList = new ArrayList(); 
 elementlist = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));       
 elementlist.addAll(driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"))); 
 List finalList = new ArrayList(); 

  for (WebElement element : elementlist)
     { 

          if(element.getAttribute("href") != null) 
           { 
                  finalList.add(element); 
           }    
       }
```

please help to solve it out.
below is the complete code.

Comment: Please add more code, like the declaration of the list and which objects are put in it.

Comment: Hi Frederik Thanks for response please check below code 
List elementList = new ArrayList();
elementlist = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
elementlist.addAll(driver.findElements(By.tagName("img")));
List finalList = new ArrayList();
for (WebElement element : elementlist)
 { if(element.getAttribute("href") != null)
  {  finalList.add(element);  }     }

Comment: Share your code by updating your question please.

Comment: User for loop like : Object element : elementList.toArray()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not declaring your Lists correctly.  You need to specify the type of object they should contain. In this case they need to be `List<WebElement>` and not just `List`.

```
 List<WebElement> elementList = new ArrayList(); 
 elementlist = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));       
 elementlist.addAll(driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"))); 
 List<WebElement> finalList = new ArrayList(); 

  for (WebElement element : elementlist)
     { 

          if(element.getAttribute("href") != null) 
           { 
                  finalList.add(element); 
           }    
       }
```